# Comparación booleana de strings

Tags: python, string, booleano

Tengo dos `string`, uno es `"ac"` y el otro `"ca"`

¿Por que cuando ejecuto `"ac"<"ca"` la operación da `True`?

Comment: @Marcos python.

Answer (score 2):

Si nos vamos a la [documentación de Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types):

> The comparison uses lexicographical ordering: first the first two items are compared, and if they differ this determines the outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted.

Traducción libre:

> La comparación utiliza [ordenamiento lexicográfico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orden_lexicogr%C3%A1fico): primero se comparan los dos primeros elementos, si difieren, determinan el resultado de la comparación; si son iguales, se comparan los siguientes dos elementos, y así sucesivamente, hasta que se agote cualquiera de las secuencias.

- En **Python 3** dónde `str` son cadenas UTF-8 el orden lexicográfico usa el identificador numérico del carácter Unicode, el llamado "[*code point*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point)"  para ordenar caracteres individuales.
- En **Python 2** se usa el orden en la tabla [ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) para ordenar cadenas `str`.

Por lo tanto, cuando haces `"ac" < "ca"` obtienes `True` porque primero se compara si `'a' < 'c'`, lo cual es cierto ya que el identificador numérico para 'a' es 97 y para 'c' es 99 y 97 es menor que 99. La comparación termina aquí. Si el primer carácter de cada cadena fueran iguales se pasaría al segundo y así sucesivamente hasta encontrar una diferencia o iterar completamente sobre al menos una de las cadenas. Si una de las cadenas es agotada la otra es considerada mayor, si ambas se agotan al mismo tiempo sin haber por tanto encontrado ninguna diferencia las cadenas son consideradas iguales.

Answer (score 0):

Se ordenan según su numero en la tabla [ASCII](https://ascii.cl/)

```js
var to = arr => console.log(arr[0] > arr[1]);

to(["!", " "]);

to(["#", "!"]);

to(["$", "#"]);

to(["%", "$"]);

to(["a", "A"]);

to(["ca", "ac"]); 

(function() {
 var first = "ca",
     second = "ac",
     firstNumber = first.charCodeAt(),
     secondNumber = second.charCodeAt();
     
     if(first > second) {
     console.log(`
     
     Primera cadena(ca) : ${firstNumber} vs 
     
     Segunda cadena(ac) : ${secondNumber}`);
     }
}());
```

**Se van comparando en orden, el primero con el primero, si son iguales, se sigue con el siguiente.**

Ejemplo:

```js
(function() {
  
  /*
  
   @Info:
   
   c => 99
   
   a => 97
   
   b => 98
   
  
  */
  
  var first = "caa",  
      second = "cab";
      // 'ca' y 'ca' son iguales, pero 'cab' es mayor que 'caa'
    
    console.log(second > first); // True
  
})();
```

Comment: La pregunta tiene como tag a python, y tu usas js, ¿piensas que tu respuesta es correcta?

Comment: Deberias comparar las ediciones con la hora de mi respuesta y además, que el OP no fué quien la editó.

Comment: Yo te lo digo para que cambies o elimines tu pregunta, ademas deberias de tomarte el tiempo y preguntar mas detalles de la pregunta ya que sin el tag del lenguaje de programacion la pregunta es demasiado amplia y no debe ser respondida ya que no es una pregunta de calidad, y eso es lo que buscamos en SO.