# ¿Porqué me da error al comparar solo estos dos números de mi diccionario?

Tags: python, if, comparaciones, else

**Recibo como parámetro**

```
22
-9052396 -7426505
5612467 -5220684
-3741637 -2571872
-592213 1451194
-4515249 3876316
9483023 287469
7177822 -2088557
987309 5642872
125703 230480
265189 -6280027
381783 -4105104
4402813 -8678907
4615966 -4058531
-1843635 -4194932
374241 2864410
-283815 1321844
5437904 -4671347
6101159 -8303733
2756781 -4491053
3147461 8241531
9385263 2630485
-1471000 6563085
```

Donde 22 es el numero de resultados, hay que comparar  cada numero de la primera conlumna con el de su derecha, así pues, habría que comprar "-9052396" con "-7426505" y devolver el mínimo de ambos.

---

He intentado abordar este problema con el siguiente código

```
numberof = int(input())
miLista={}
myAnswer={}
for i in range(numberof):
    set = input().split()
    miLista[i]=set
for i in miLista:
    if miLista[i][0]<miLista[i][1]:
        myAnswer[i]=(miLista[i][0])
    else:
        myAnswer[i] =(miLista[i][1])
a=myAnswer.values()
b=a.replace("dict_values","").replace("(","").replace("]","").replace(")","")
c=b.replace("[","").replace("'","").replace(",","")
print(c)
```

Y recibo como resultado lo siguiente, donde no se compara debidamente los indices 13 y 14

```
-7426505 
-5220684
-2571872
-592213
-4515249
287469 
-2088557 
5642872 
125703 
-6280027 
-4105104 
-8678907 
-4058531 
-1843635 # Error
2864410 # Error
-283815 
-4671347 
-8303733 
-4491053 
3147461 
2630485 
-1471000
```

Al desbugearlo cuando se llega al indice 13 y 14, en vez de entrar en la condicion

```
if miLista[i][0]<miLista[i][1]:
        myAnswer[i]=(miLista[i][0])
```

Entra en el else

```
else:
   myAnswer[i] =(miLista[i][1])
```

¿Porqué?

Comment: Te están fallando más casos, así a simple vista veo que en la primera y en la tercera también te lo esta devolviendo mal. Tiene pinta que esta comparando los números como si todos fuesen positivos, sin tener en cuenta si son negativos.

Comment: Voy a probar, espero que no sea esa idiotez porque llevo casi dos horas con este programa tan simple

Comment: Yo creo que es que estás comparando los números como cadenas. Debes convertirlos a `int()`

Comment: Como dice abulafia es tan simple como que comparas dos cadenas (orden lexicográfico, el carácter "1" de "-1843635" es menor que el "4" de "-4194932" ) en vez de dos enteros, basta con hacer `int(miLista[i][0]) < int(miLista[i][1])`.

Comment: Vaya. Resulta que ese era el problema.

Comment: Esta pregunta hace referencia al mismo problema que presentas: [Comparación boleana de strings](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129456/15089), por si aclara algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A la hora de llegar a la siguiente condición:

```
if miLista[i][0]<miLista[i][1]:
        myAnswer[i]=(miLista[i][0])
    else:
        myAnswer[i] =(miLista[i][1])
```

Estaba comparando dos cadenas, lo cual daba lugar al error. Habría que pasar las listas a un entero de la siguiente manera:

```
if int(miLista[i][0])<int(miLista[i][1]):
        myAnswer[i]=(miLista[i][0])
    else:
        myAnswer[i] =(miLista[i][1])
```

Lo  cual soluciona mi error.