# Cómo obtener el menor de tres números

Tags: python, if, condiciones, comparaciones, else

**Recibo como input**

```
28
9193542 -1720829 -6332906
8611600 -4206697 -2147553
-9612077 3187901 9866925
1555504 5242895 -2556041
-5934423 -6615366 5714717
9791988 2855524 -7890125
549120 -547245 4656995
-2581321 4596487 -1553344
8545516 1444625 3848862
-5793964 -9659685 1897955
9893708 9533856 -9822874
-6439197 8145456 -4029572
1413249 8533379 9158329
1280175 88884 4401224
8724133 4154461 7785857
4438851 3946449 641382
6548726 -5504430 -9905862
1205721 1914249 4690624
9652376 459765 -3864750
3501238 4665801 -3524436
-4600806 4559509 -3990580
-4423680 8120312 -5845123
1546748 -466438 -7311743
705077 -9186263 2777140
-4893698 9537870 -3068399
-7107840 3976721 -9121949
3533541 525447 -4626380
3627678 -8268831 7287868
```

Donde hay que comparar cada fila entre sí, dando 28 resultados. He intentado abordarlo con el siguiente código:

```
numberof = int(input())
miLista={}
myAnswer={}
for i in range(numberof):
    set = input().split()
    miLista[i]=set
for i in miLista:
    if int(miLista[i][0]) < int(miLista[i][1] and int(miLista[i][0]) < int(miLista[i][2])):
        myAnswer[i] = (miLista[i][0])
    elif int(miLista[i][1]) < int(miLista[i][0] and int(miLista[i][1]) < int(miLista[i][2])):
        myAnswer[i] = (miLista[i][1])
    elif int(miLista[i][2]) < int(miLista[i][1] and int(miLista[i][2]) < int(miLista[i][0])):
        myAnswer[i] = (miLista[i][2])

a=str(myAnswer.values())
b=a.replace("dict_values","").replace("(","").replace("]","").replace(")","")
c=b.replace("[","").replace("'","").replace(",","")
print(c)
```

Pero como output recibo comparaciones erroneas, sin ir más lejos, la primera linea devuelve como menor -1720829. ¿Porqué?
**Hice una pregunta parecida [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151987/porqu%C3%A9-me-da-error-al-comparar-solo-estos-dos-n%C3%BAmeros-de-mi-diccionario/151990#151990)**

Comment: Tienes un error tipográfico, escribes los `if` algo así: `if int(a) < int(b and int(a) < int(c)):` nota la falta del paréntesis en la segunda conversión. Debiera ser así: `if int(a) < int(b) and int(a) < int(c)):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El fallo lo tienes en que te falta incluir paréntesis para cada comparación que haces, debería ser así:

```
if (int(miLista[i][0]) < int(miLista[i][1]) and (int(miLista[i][0]) < int(miLista[i][2]))):
    myAnswer[i] = (miLista[i][0])
elif (int(miLista[i][1]) < int(miLista[i][0]) and (int(miLista[i][1]) < int(miLista[i][2]))):
    myAnswer[i] = (miLista[i][1])
elif (int(miLista[i][2]) < int(miLista[i][1]) and (int(miLista[i][2]) < int(miLista[i][0]))):
    myAnswer[i] = (miLista[i][2])
```

Pero es mas fácil si usas la función [`min`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_min.htm) que devuelve el mínimo de los números que le pases, ahorrándote todos los `if` y `else if` dejándolo en una sola linea:

```
myAnswer[i] = min(int(miLista[i][0]), int(miLista[i][1]), int(miLista[i][2]))
```

Comment: Ahora me da las comparaciones correctamente. Pero ¿Porqué me falla?

Comment: Por falta de paréntesis, voy a editar la respuesta para que lo veas.