# Ordenar elementos númerados estilo lista (Y.x.x.x) en python y pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un Dataframe creado con Pandas cuyos elementos tienen un indice del estilo:

```
C.0 Introducción
C.1 Creando el personaje
C.2 Caracteristicas
C.22 Viajando por el mundo
C.10 Enemigos
C.7 Tiendas y mercados
c.2.2 Tipos de caracteristicas
```

En caso de hacer un sort_values se ordena como si fueran strings quedando:

```
C.0 Introducción
C.1 Creando el personaje
C.10 Enemigos
C.2 Caracteristicas
C.2.2 Tipos de caracteristicas
C.22 Viajando por el mundo
C.7 Tiendas y mercados
```

Evidentemente no es el resultado esperado.
El caso es que no sé exactamente como se llama este tipo de ordenación ni si ya existe alguna función que lo haga.
La idea es reindexar las filas del dataframe en base a la columna de indice.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato son los índices? Tal y como lo presentas son efectivamente cadenas Python (object) y por tanto se le aplica un [orden lexicográfico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129456/comparaci%c3%b3n-booleana-de-strings/129478#129478). ¿Podrías agregar un [mcve] para facilitar la reproducción?

Comment: Efectivamente los datos son cadenas de texto con una númeración, lo estoy haciendo para ordenar titulos, subtitulos y similares en un indice, el ejemplo es el dado en la pregunta ya que el texto que viene detrás no creo que sea relevante sin embargo, si sirve de ayuda, lo pongo sin problemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como se ha comentado, Python por defecto lleva a cabo un ordenamiento lexicográfico de las cadenas, lo que tu quieres se conoce generalmente como ordenamiento natural que no es más que ordenar alfabéticamente las cadenas pero tratando las subcadenas de dígitos contiguos como enteros.

Si quieres implementarlo por ti mismo la forma que plantea @PatricioMoracho en su respuesta es la aproximación general.

Otra opción si no te importa instalar un paquete externo es usar [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) que puedes instalar vía *pip* y que te simplifica la tarea:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from natsort import natsorted, ns


data = io.StringIO(
'''
Título,A
C.0 Introducción,0
C.1 Creando el personaje,1
C.2 Caracteristicas,2
C.22 Viajando por el mundo,2
C.10 Enemigos,4
C.7 Tiendas y mercados,5
c.2.2 Tipos de caracteristicas,6  
B.1.3 Foo, 7
B.1.1.2 Bar, 8
A.77 Hola, 9               
'''
)


df = pd.read_csv(data, index_col=0)
```

con esto tenemos el siguiente DataFrame ejemplo:

> ```
> >>> df
>                                 A
> Título                           
> C.0 Introducción                0
> C.1 Creando el personaje        1
> C.2 Caracteristicas             2
> C.22 Viajando por el mundo      2
> C.10 Enemigos                   4
> C.7 Tiendas y mercados          5
> c.2.2 Tipos de caracteristicas  6
> B.1.3 Foo                       7
> B.1.1.2 Bar                     8
> A.77 Hola                       9
> ```

Podemos ordenarlo con:

> ```
> >>> df = df.reindex(natsorted(df.index, alg=ns.IGNORECASE))
>
> >>> df2
>                                 A
> Título                           
> A.77 Hola                       9
> B.1.1.2 Bar                     8
> B.1.3 Foo                       7
> C.0 Introducción                0
> C.1 Creando el personaje        1
> C.2 Caracteristicas             2
> c.2.2 Tipos de caracteristicas  6
> C.7 Tiendas y mercados          5
> C.10 Enemigos                   4
> C.22 Viajando por el mundo      2
> ```

Comment: Buena respuesta también y más sencilla! no conocía `natsort` tiene muy buena pinta.

Comment: muchas gracias, es justo lo que buscaba, por un lado el tipo de ordenación y como abordarla, en ocasiones mas que no saber como buscar es que no sabes que es lo que buscas y google no ayuda precisamente.

Answer (score 1):

Tal como dice @FJSevilla se está aplicando un orden lexicografico, sobre la columna. Para ordenar adecuadamente esto, hay que trabajar un poco primero:

- Separar cada parte de la cadena (el punto es el dato que separa cada valor)
- Convertir los números a enteros, en estos casos el orden debe ser numérico
- Con cada elemento separado en una lista ya podremos ordenar adecuadamente

Veamos primero un ejemplo con una lista estándar de Python:

```
idxs = ['C.0','C.1','C.2','C.22','C.10','C.7','c.2.2']

def try_to_int(s):
  try:
      return int(s)
  except ValueError:
      return s.upper()

def make_sorteable_col(s):
  return list(map(try_to_int, s.split('.')))

print(idxs)
idxs.sort(key=lambda s: make_sorteable_col(s))
print(idxs)
```

La salida:

```
['C.0', 'C.1', 'C.2', 'C.22', 'C.10', 'C.7', 'c.2.2'] # Original
['C.0', 'C.1', 'C.2', 'c.2.2', 'C.7', 'C.10', 'C.22'] # Ordenada
```

La función `try_to_int` intentará devolver un entero, en caso que no se pueda convertir el valor de entrada, se retornará una cadena en mayúscula. Luego, la función `make_sorteable_col` separa la cadena original por los puntos y aplica `try_to_int` a cada elemento, por último retorna una lista, que contendrá cadenas y enteros. Esta lista podrá usarse finalmente para ordenar mediante `sort`, el parámetro `key` establece el mecanismo para obtener la "clave" que usaremos para el orden, en este casos será el retorno de nuestra función `make_sorteable_col`.

Con `Pandas` es un poco más complejo, por que hasta dónde sé no hay forma de usar una función para obtener la `key` del orden, entonces una posibilidad es:

#### Crear una nueva columna y ordenar por esta

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idxs = ['C.0','C.1','C.2','C.22','C.10','C.7','c.2.2']
nombres = ['Introducción', 'Creando el personaje', 'Caracteristicas','Viajando por el mundo','Enemigos','Tiendas y mercados','Tipos de caracteristicas']
df = pd.DataFrame({'idx': idxs, 'nombre': nombres})

def try_to_int(s):
  try:
      return int(s)
  except ValueError:
      return s.upper()

def make_sorteable_col(s):
  return list(map(try_to_int, s.split('.')))

df["new_col"] = df.idx.map(make_sorteable_col)
df = df.sort_values(by=['new_col'])
print(df)
```

La salida:

```
     idx                    nombre    new_col
0    C.0              Introducción     [C, 0]
1    C.1      Creando el personaje     [C, 1]
2    C.2           Caracteristicas     [C, 2]
6  c.2.2  Tipos de caracteristicas  [C, 2, 2]
5    C.7        Tiendas y mercados     [C, 7]
4   C.10                  Enemigos    [C, 10]
3   C.22     Viajando por el mundo    [C, 22]
```

Como verás, terminamos con el `df` correctamente ordenado, pero con una columna, tal vez innecesaria que deberemos "dropear" luego.

O también:

#### Usando una rutina de orden ([fuente](https://gist.github.com/hellpanderrr/599bce82ecc6934aa9e1))

Aquí la idea es convertir la columna que esperamos ordenar en una lista, ordenar la misma tal como hicimos en el primero de los ejemplos  y luego simplemente ordenar el `dataframe` por índice.

```
def sort_df(df, column_idx, key):
    '''Takes dataframe, column index and custom function for sorting, 
    returns dataframe sorted by this column using this function'''

    col = df.ix[:,column_idx]
    temp = np.array(col.values.tolist())
    order = sorted(range(len(temp)), key=lambda j: key(temp[j]))
    return df.ix[order]

df = sort_df(df, 0, make_sorteable_col)
print(df)
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, y tal como dice  por desgracia no existe forma de ordenar vía `key` como en `.sort()`/`sorted()` de Python (lo he echado de menos más de una vez....XD). En su día se abrió esta discusión sobre si implementarlo o no pero a día de hoy sigue sin ser posible.